# Bluetooth headphones behaving strangely on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

I have a Sennheiser Bluetooth headset that connected to my machine through a Bluetooth dongle. It uses the Widcomm drivers (latest version).

It worked perfectly when set up but after a while the speakers will stop working in Skype (still working if I listen to music though). Sometimes uninstalling Widdcomm Bluetooth drivers or simply removing and re-adding the Bluetooth device has fixed this but the last time it happened this hasn't worked.

It's a very specific problem but I was wandering if anyone could point me in the right direction to debug what's going on under the hood.

I'm currently programming Windows client applications so I have a good technical knowledge but I can't for the life of me work out what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try running the model in the Windows Compatibility Center (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/default.aspx). Sometimes, updated driver information will be included with the product.